# Run a random algorithm mutiple times and average over the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, random

I have the following random selection script:

```
import random

length_of_list = 200
my_list = list(range(length_of_list))
num_selections = 10

numbers = random.sample(my_list, num_selections)
```

It looks at a list of predetermined size and randomly selects 10 numbers. Is there a way to run this section 500 times and then get the top 10 numbers which were selected the most? I was thinking that I could feed the numbers into a dictionary and then get the top 10 numbers from there. So far, I've done the following:

```
for run in range(0, 500):
    numbers = random.sample(my_list, num_selections)
    for number in numbers:
        current_number = my_dict.get(number)
        key_number = number
        my_dict.update(number = number+1)

    print(my_dict)
```

Here I want the code to take the current number assigned to that key and then add 1, but I cannot manage to make it work. It seems like the key for the dictionary update has to be that specific key, cannot insert a variable.. Also, I think having this nested loop might not be so efficient as I have to run this 500 times 1500 times 23... so I am concerned about performance. If anyone has an idea of what I should try, it would be great! Thanks

**SOLUTION**:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict

length_of_list = 50
my_list = list(range(length_of_list))
num_selections = 10

my_dict = dict.fromkeys(my_list)

di = defaultdict(int)
for run in range(0, 500):
    numbers = random.sample(my_list, num_selections)
    for number in numbers:
        di[number] += 1


def get_top_numbers(data, n, order=False):
    """Gets the top n numbers from the dictionary"""
    top = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:n]
    if order:
        return OrderedDict(top)
    return dict(top)


print(get_top_numbers(di, n=10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of collections module,
So basically, you create a `defaultdict` with default value `0` and then iterate over your `numbers` list and update the value of the number to `+=1`

```
from collections import defaultdict
di = defaultdict(int)
for run in range(0, 500):
    numbers = random.sample(my_list, num_selections)
    for number in numbers:
        di[number] += 1

    print(di)
```

Answer (score 4):

`my_dict.update(number = number+1)` in this line you are assigning a new value to a variable inside the parentheses of a function call. Unless you're giving the function a [kwarg](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html) called `number` with value `number+1` this in the following error:
`TypeError: 'number' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Also `dict.update` doesn't accept an integer but another dictionary. You should read the documentation about this function: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/dictionary_update.htm
Here it say's `dict.update(dict2)` takes a dictionary which it will integrate into `dict`. See example below:

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 17}
dict2 = {'Gender': 'female' }

dict.update(dict2)
print ("updated dict : ", dict)
```

Gives as result:
`updated dict : {'Gender': 'female', 'Age': 17, 'Name': 'Zara'}`

So far for the errors in your code, I see a good answer is already given so I won't repeat him.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for this task `collections.Counter` which provides addition method. So you will use two counters one which is sum of all and second which contains count of samples.

```
counter = collections.Counter()
for run in range(500):
    samples = random.sample(my_list, num_samples)
    sample_counter = collections.Counter(samples)
    counter = counter + sample_counter
```